# Skype: Don't show me as active when I turn my PC on

Tags: skype, status

I don't want to be inundated by "Hello's" every time I boot my PC.

*Is there a way of showing me as 'off-line' until I choose to change my online status?*

Answer (score 6):

Skype remembers your last status before you sign out. If you want to appear offline the next time your computer starts / you sign in, simply set yourself to appear offline before signing out.